# How to debug authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to debug authentication in a HTML5 client for Azure mobile services?
I've developed a simple mobile service, and tries to call it form a HTML5 client. In my javascript I have the following code.

```
        client.login("microsoftaccount").then(refreshAuthDisplay, function (error) {
            alert("login error: " + error);
        });
```

When calling this it redirects me to a localhost address. Is it possible to debug this locally or do I have to publish my service and webpage to Azure?

Comment: Are you using the .NET backend or the node.js backend?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Azure Mobile Services or Azure App Service Mobile Apps?  They are different.

Things common to both:
If you are running the HTML5 client via a local server, then set up a local debugging proxy like Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) - this will allow you to monitor the interactions between your browser, your website that is serving your code (on your local machine) and the authentication gateway running within Azure Mobile Services.

You will also be able to put breakpoints and such like in your .NET code that is serving the HTML5 client so you can figure out the state of things in your backend.